Having trouble retrieving data from mySQL in web development project
I'm working on a personal project trying to learn web/full-stack development where I'm trying to recreate the NYT Connections game.
I've created a database.js file using node.js that successfully connects to and retrieves data from a local database. The goal is to have new words load into the document based on what the current date is. I have a second  (script.js) file for all the client-side interactions (i.e. dark/light mode, other miscellaneous functions) and that's the only script I have linked to the HTML file, but I consistently get browser errors when I try to import functions into the script.js file from the database.js file that send queries to the db and return an array of words.
My current working theory is that it has something to do with the mysql2 (and dotenv) imports in database.js file, and it's causing errors in the browser. I've watched tutorials and I'm thinking my solution is using express (also experimenting with) - would this resolve my issue?
//database.js
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
}).promise();

export async function initGameBoard() {
    const [words] = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE set_id = (SELECT set_id FROM Sets WHERE publish_date = current_date())");
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {arr[i] = words[i].word}
    return arr;
}

//script.js
import { initGameBoard } from './database.js'

//fetches data from DB to initialize first tile titles
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    words = initGameBoard();
 });


database.js and any scripts that access the database will be running on the server.
script.js and any scripts that access the web page DOM (such as with document.addEventListener()) are running in your browser (the client).
You can't import a server script from the browser. On the server, you need to start a web server (such as using express as mentioned) and then the client will make a HTTP request to retrieve the information.
Here's some documentation on how to use express: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html
